# How to change the starting position of progress in circular progress bar?

Tags: ios

I am using DACircularProgressView. Here i want to change the starting position of the progress i.e., whether top, bottom, sides or at required position. How to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know about the library you use, but maybe you can simply apply a rotation to the view?

Comment: I solved the issue. [self.circularProgressView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 2)]; By changing the number in this line.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.circularProgressView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 2)];
```

by changing the number in (-M_PI / 2) we can change the position.(i.e., 2)